# Accessing Dropdown value in SAP table cell

Tags: hp-uft

[image]
I am using UFT 15.0.2 On SAP 760

I need to select a value from the dropdown list that is inside a table.

Object spy can only see the Table and not the individual items within.
Tried to record and it captures nothing.
Tried to use Insight Objects and it captures that, but it will not run to select the dropdown value

The following code all work with no error BUT it does not actually select the dropdown value or put a value in the cell of the table

```
SAPGuiSession("S").SAPGuiWindow("Manage The Day").SAPGuiTable("Measurement Document Details").ActivateCell 1, "Service.Type"
SAPGuiSession("S").SAPGuiWindow("Manage The Day").SAPGuiTable("Measurement Document Details").OpenPossibleEntries 1, "Service.Type"
SAPGuiSession("S").SAPGuiWindow("Manage The Day").SAPGuiTable("Measurement Document Details").SetCellData 1, "Service.Type", "A"
```

I continually get error message from SAP: `E:ZW:999 PM06 Order must have Service Type-Please Reenter`

I have tried SendKeys like: `SAPGuiSession("S").SAPGuiWindow("Manage The Day").SendKey TAB`
And that works but does not select a value.

Any ideas please